# Can I use the SIFT feature detector on data other than images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction, sift

I know how to use SIFT algorithm for images but I never use it for other kinds of data. I have tabular data (x, y, z, time) where x,y,z is the joint position along x, y, z coordinates. Now, can I apply the SIFT algorithm to this data to find features that will act as input to traditional machine learning algorithms, like SVM, DT, etc.?

Comment: Check out this paper: [Dense Bag-of-Temporal-SIFT-Words for Time Series Classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01799) (2016). After reading it, maybe you can provide an answer to your own question ;)

Comment: @nbro Thank you